# Why is my response JSON object missing `prompt_filter_results` when serializing the Azure OpenAI response object into a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, serialization, azure-openai

I run some Azure OpenAI request, and try to convert the response object into JSON:

```
#Note: This code sample requires OpenAI Python library version 1.0.0 or higher.
import json
import pprint
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint = "https://xxxxxx.openai.azure.com/",
  api_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  api_version="2023-07-01-preview"
)

message_text = [{"role":"system","content":"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."}]
completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-4xxxxxxxx", 
  messages = message_text,
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=800,
  top_p=0.95,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
  stop=None
)

print('completion:\n')
pprint.pprint(completion)

# Convert Python object to JSON
json_data = json.dumps(completion, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4)

# Print JSON
print(json_data)
```

Looking at  the output, the response object `completion` contains:

```
ChatCompletion(id='chatcmpl-xxxxxxxxx', choices=[Choice(finish_reason='stop', index=0, logprobs=None, message=ChatCompletionMessage(content='Great! How can I assist you today?', role='assistant', function_call=None, tool_calls=None), content_filter_results={'hate': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'self_harm': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'sexual': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'violence': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}})], created=1709313222, model='gpt-4', object='chat.completion', system_fingerprint='fp_xxxxx', usage=CompletionUsage(completion_tokens=9, prompt_tokens=18, total_tokens=27), prompt_filter_results=[{'prompt_index': 0, 'content_filter_results': {'hate': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'self_harm': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'sexual': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}, 'violence': {'filtered': False, 'severity': 'safe'}}}])
```

However, the corresponding JSON object is missing `prompt_filter_results`:

```
{
    "id": "chatcmpl-xxxxxxx",
    "choices": [
        {
            "finish_reason": "stop",
            "index": 0,
            "logprobs": null,
            "message": {
                "content": "Great! How can I assist you today?",
                "role": "assistant",
                "function_call": null,
                "tool_calls": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "created": 1709313222,
    "model": "gpt-4",
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "system_fingerprint": "fp_xxxxx",
    "usage": {
        "completion_tokens": 9,
        "prompt_tokens": 18,
        "total_tokens": 27
    }
}
```

Why is my response JSON object missing `prompt_filter_results` when serializing the Azure OpenAI response object into a JSON object?

Comment: The `ChatCompletion` class must have customized its JSON formatting, and it doesn't include that field.

Comment: That maybe be related to the fact that "openai" library is made by openai, not Azure, and those filters does not exist on openai side